# PDO retrieve table data

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to PDO having used mySQL in the past. I have created a seperate file to connect to the database.

```
<?php
 $dbHost='localhost';
 $databaseName='dm_projectdb';
 $username='blah';
 $password='blah';

 $db= new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost; dbName=$databaseName;
    charset=utf8", "$username","$password");
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
                PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);  
            ?>
```

And in another file im trying to retrieve and print the table.

```
<?php   
require_once('connect.php');
$sql= "SELECT CourseID, Course_Name  FROM coursename WHERE CourseID = 1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':CourseID', $CourseID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

The table is called coursename with Course_Name and CourseID rows.
When I run this I get `Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in N:\ftp\project\comparison.php on line 44`

and

`Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in N:\ftp\project\comparison.php on line 44`

What am I doing wrong? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: should be `$db` not `$pdo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use what you have set, and that is `$db`, not `$pdo`:

```
$db= new PDO
```

Abd also, you didn't add your named placeholder on the query statement:

```
CourseID = :CourseID
```

So finally:

```
require 'connect.php';
$sql = "SELECT CourseID, Course_Name  FROM coursename WHERE CourseID = :CourseID";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':CourseID', $CourseID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($results);
```

In `connect.php`:

```
$dbHost ='localhost';
$databaseName ='dm_projectdb';
$username ='blah';
$password ='blah';

$db= new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$databaseName;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Comment: Just tried what you said and it removed the error but i'm getting     "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' in N:\ftp\compc\d10mcfm\project\comparison.php:44 Stack trace: #0 N:\ftp\compc\d10mcfm\project\comparison.php(44): PDO->prepare('SELECT CourseID...') #1 {main} thrown in N:\ftp\project\comparison.php on line 44" error now. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: @mkra did you forget to include the connection file?

Comment: Yes i did; no errors now but instead of the table being printed it says "Array ( ) <" on the website

Comment: @mkra and make sure that `$CourseID` has a value. turn on error reporting

Comment: $CourseID has a value in the table if thats what you mean and im not sure how to turn on error reporting sorry. I am using phpmyadmin if that matters.

Comment: @mkra no, what i mean is make sure `$CourseID` is not empty. try this http://pastebin.com/ps40uUem

Comment: Thank you that worked. I just have to get it to not display just courseID ie.1 and coursename ie.computing istead of currently  "Array ( [0] => Array ( [CourseID] => 1 [Course_Name] => Computing ) ) <".