# PDO Output print in table

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to print in a table but Im not sure how to using PDO. Heres my attempt.

```
require_once('connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT CourseID, Module_Name,ModuleID, Module_Code, Module_Year  FROM  
coursemodule ORDER BY ModuleID ASC";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':ModuleID', $CourseID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
while ($output = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
   echo "<p>" . $output->Module_Name  . " " . $output->Module_Code  . "</p>\n";

}
```

and

```
     <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Modules from Current Course</th>
       <th>Modules from New Course</th>

    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody>
```

I know I have to store the data from the query then print it out in the table but any attempts have lead nowhere. Can anyone help?

EDIT Latest attempt

```
 try
{
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM coursemodule WHERE ModuleID=?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
    $_POST['ModuleID']
));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<h1>Course Modules</h1>


<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>

 <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
```

```
     <?php 
     foreach ($result as $row)
     {

         <tr>
        <td>echo {$row['ModuleID']}</td>

        <td>


     } // End Foreach
  ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Getting the error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'' related to my attempt to echo in the table.

Comment: [**Reading the manual**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) would help. Plus, checking for errors.

Comment: In order to print something in the table, you need to add rows and columns to it.  At the moment your code is just echoing paragraphs with the module name and module code.  Is your query returning anything?  Where is the problem occurring?

Comment: @ymas The querry is working and printing out fine but outside the table. I just don't know how to store the module name/code and then reopen it below in the table class to print out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No errors showing up when I run it. I have looked at the manual as suggested and will try some things it suggests.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, plus `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so.

Comment: @Fred-ii-I added the code you suggested and got the following errors 'Notice: Undefined variable: db' and 'Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object'.

Comment: Post your DB connection codes then, while replacing actual credentials with `xxx`.

Comment: @mkra, the notice that you receive is because you don't use the variable `$db` (you need to change it to whatever variable you are using to represent your PDO object) -- if you're saying that the query executes and everything is ok on that front, then you just need to populate the table.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Do you mean my seperate connection file?

Comment: Yes, the connection file.

Comment: Wait a minute, I was looking at your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27179304/ where the answer given uses `WHERE CourseID = :CourseID` but you're not doing that in this one, that's the reason it's failing, you're not binding to anything. You need to do the same thing here. However, you can't bind a column for `ORDER BY ModuleID` even if you tried/did `ORDER BY :ModuleID` that won't work.

Comment: I tried removing the 'order by' and using the 'WHERE CourseID = :CourseID' stopping it from printing.

Comment: Where is `$CourseID` being defined? Your question/code is missing a lot of code to back it up with.

Comment: It isn't but my code won't print out without it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no issues with the query then in order to populate the table, you need to add rows and columns to it.  For example you can do something like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Modules from Current Course</th>
      <th>Modules from New Course</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($modules as $module): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $module['Module_Name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $module['Module_Code']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Do not put the SQL statements in the same place as you put your view code (this will be a nightmare to maintain in the future and is a habit you should **not** get into).  In my solution, I assume you assign the result set from the query to a variable called `$modules`.

See the documentation for `fetchAll`:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

*Note* You will need to adapt my snippet to your needs, I'm just showing you an *example* of populating a table with rows and columns.

**Update**
Try changing the table generating code in your last attempt to this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['ModuleID']; ?></td>
      <td colspan="3">
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the way you shown not recommended or was that in reference to my code thanks?

Comment: I was referring to mixing SQL and HTML view code together.  That is not recommended.

Comment: The reason for the error message in your latest attempt is that you are putting HTML directly inside PHP, look at my answer and try to mirror that in your code.